# Haskell: Running a list of IO operations over a single value

Tags: haskell

if I have a number of functions that are `string -> IO ()`, is there a tidy way to apply them all to a single value in sequence.

```
op1, op2, op3 :: String -> IO ()

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let str = "test"
  op1 str
  op2 str
  op3 str
```

with out having to write out str each time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use a map and partial application of function application (`$`):

```
mapM ($ str) [op1,op2,op3]
```

Don't want the result? Fine.

```
mapM_ ($ str) [op1,op2,op3]
```

Or use `Data.Foldable`:

```
for_ [op1,op2,op3] ($ str)
```

EDIT:

Expanding on the commentary of `for_` being a replacement for `forM_`.

The same can be said about `mapM`/`mapM_`.  These are artifacts of history - the operations are specialized to Monads and could, argueably should, be deleted.  The Applicative alternative is `traverse` and `traverse_`.

Comment: sigh .. for some reason when I tried this earlier, I got an error. I am not sure what I did wrong then. Thanks a lot.

Comment: thanks for the extra options. is that `for_` different to `forM_`

Comment: `forM_` is an artifact of history - it is specialized to Monads.  Now that all Monads are also Applicative you can always use `for_` and we should some day remove `forM_`.

Comment: If they're `IO ()` operations, then `mapM_` or `for_` is almost certainly preferable.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend the `for_` or `traverse_` approach, but note that these `Monoid` instances exist:

```
 Monoid b => Monoid (a -> b)
 Monoid a => Monoid (IO a)
 Monoid ()
```

So in this particular case, this works:

```
  mconcat [op1, op2, op3] str
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do

```
op1, op2, op3 :: String -> IO ()

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let str = "test"
    mconcat (sequence [op1, op2, op3] str)
```

This is somewhat complicated: `sequence` here is specialized to type

```
[String -> IO ()] -> String -> [IO ()]
```

while `mconcat` simply takes a list of IO actions (type `[IO ()]`) and returns a single IO action (type `IO ()`).

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, this one using `ZipList` from `Control.Applicative`:

```
let ZipList ios = ZipList [op1,op2,op3] <*> ZipList (repeat str) 
 in sequence ios
```